# Can manifold subsets always be made into submanifolds?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Related question: [Are manifold subsets submanifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297573/are-manifold-subsets-submanifolds)

---

Assume all manifolds, topological or smooth discussed here [have dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if) and do not have boundary.

Let $A'$ and $B'$ be sets with $A' \subseteq B'$.

**Question A**: Are these correct?

1. As far as I know, all sets can be made into topological spaces.
2. By (1), make the sets $A'$ and $B'$ into, respectively, the topological spaces $A$ and $B$.
3. I haven't thought about whether there are some sets that cannot be given topological spaces that enable them to become smooth or topological manifolds, but as far as I know, some topological spaces cannot be made into smooth manifolds or even topological manifolds...such as ones that aren't Hausdorff I guess.
4. By (3), assume $A$ and $B$ from (2) can be made into smooth manifolds $(A,\mathscr A)$ and $(B,\mathscr B)$ where $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$ are smooth atlases.
5. By (4) and the above [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297573/are-manifold-subsets-submanifolds), $(A,\mathscr A)$ is not necessarily a (regular/an embedded) smooth submanifold of $(B,\mathscr B)$ or even an immersed smooth submanifold.

**Question B**: Does there exist a smooth atlas $\mathcal A$ where $(A,\mathcal A)$ becomes a smooth submanifold of $(B,\mathscr B)$?

- I hope Question $B$ is equivalent to both
- > (C) "If a topological subspace can become a smooth manifold, then can it become a smooth submanifold?"
- > (D) "Can smooth manifold subsets $(N,\mathscr N)$ of smooth manifolds $(M, \mathscr M)$ always be made into smooth submanifolds $(N,\mathcal N)$ of $(M, \mathscr M)$?"
- If one of (1)-(5) is wrong, then $B$, $C$ or $D$ could be meaningless or, if meaningful, not equivalent to the other meaningful ones. **Please answer the meaningful ones among (B),(C) and (D), and please point out which are equivalent or not.**
- Not concerned about uniqueness at this point. You can say something about uniqueness if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Your statements in **Question A** are all essentially correct. Whether or not you can put a manifold topology on a set depends only on the cardinality of the set. For sets with cardinality greater than that of $\mathbb R,$ the answer depends on your axioms:

- If your definition of manifold includes second-countability, then any set strictly larger than $\mathbb R$ cannot be made a manifold.
- If not, every set can be made a 0-dimensional manifold. (If you insist on positive dimension, I think by assuming the axiom of choice you can prove that all sets with cardinality at least that of $\mathbb R$ can be made manifolds.)

Regardless, I think this point is a tangent from your main concern:

**Question B.** You can answer this without needing to think about smooth structure at all: If $A$ has an atlas making it a smooth submanifold of $B,$ then $A$ is a topological submanifold of $B.$ This makes things much easier, since there is no arbitrary choice to be made when talking about topological submanifolds: a subset $A \subset B$ is a topological submanifold if and only the induced topology makes $A$ a topological manifold.

So, if $A$ has some atlas making it a smooth submanifold, then $A$ is a topological manifold in the induced topology. Thus any subset $A \subset B$ which is *not* a topological manifold in the induced topology (e.g. one that is not locally Euclidean) provides a counterexample.

Comment: First-countability is not relevant (it's immediate from being locally Euclidean), only second-countability is.  The continuum hypothesis is also not relevant--it would be relevant only for cardinalities less than that of $\mathbb{R}$, not greater.

Comment: @EricWofsey: thanks for the corrections. The CH remark was a hangover from before I remembered 0-dimensional manifolds exist and reframed that point with the >|R| condition.

Comment: Thanks Anthony Carapetis. Actually, I think I realized a way (or another way) my question is kind of wrong. I actually think I implicitly assume "From the atlases $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$, we can already say whether or not $(A, \mathscr A)$ is or isn't a regular/an embedded submanifold of $(B, \mathscr B)$." Is this statement wrong (whether or not I actually implicitly assumed it)?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland: So long as $A$ is a subset of $B$, this statement is not wrong - it's just asking whether the inclusion map $A \to B$ is a smooth embedding when considered as a function between manifolds $(A,\mathscr A) \to (B,\mathscr B).$

Comment: Anthony Carapetis thank you so much. Will analyze your answer later.

Comment: @EricWofsey and Anthony Carapetis, I analyzed. Not sure I understand. Counterexample to what? It sounds like you're answering the question "Does every $\mathcal A$ make $(A,\mathcal A)$ a submanifold of $(B,\mathscr B)$?" I know the answer is no. My question is if there necessarily exists some $\mathcal A$ that makes $(A,\mathcal A)$ a submanifold of $(B,\mathscr B)$. Edit: Oh I forgot to say topological or smooth. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: @SeleneAuckland: I mean a counterexample $A$ to the claim "for all $A$, there exists some $\mathcal A$ s.t. ...". If $A$ is not a topological submanifold, then *every* $\mathcal A$ will fail to make it a smooth submanifold.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis That should be part of answering question (A), I think. Anyway, question (B) is supposed to be as follows (I might have been unclear): Question (B) assumes there exists some $\mathscr A$ for $A$ and then asks if there is a $\mathcal A$ (again, given the existence of a $\mathscr A$). So some but not all topological subspaces $X$ can become topological manifolds or topological submanifolds, and thus, I ask about that $X$'s that can become.